# Java library architecture

Tags: java, design-patterns

1) There is **Somelib** which is added as *jar* in **SomeProject**.

2) In **SomeProject** there is the **somePackage.SomeClass** which implements **SomeLib.SomeInterface**.

3) **SomeLib** must be able to create **somePackage.SomeClass** instance without building **SomeLib** each time

How is it possible without using reflection? It's impossible to write in **SomeLib** something like *import somePackage.Someclass*.

I'm using Netbeans.

PS I'm newbie to Java and I tried to be as clear as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just could add a hard-coded dependency, but you should avoid that at all costs if you are planning to re-use your library (and even if you don't)

**Instead use this pattern:**

1. Create a **factory** for creating `SomeInterface` implementations in your library. (See [Factory method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) for more information)
2. In `SomeProject` you have to register your `SomeClass` with that factory. You can use a static initializer in conjuction with `Class.forName` for that.

   ```
   public class SomeClass {
       static {
         SomeFactory.registerSomeImplementation(SomeClass.class)
       }
   }

   Class.forName("somePackage.SomeClass") // Alternative 1 
   SomeClass.class.getName();             // Alternative 2
   ```

   Both alternatives load the class and run the static initializer, but the second one offers some better refactoring opportunities.
   Don't be confused with `Class.forName`: One of the other answers suggested using it for creating a `SomeClass` instance in the *library*. But here you use it in the *project* for loading the class and thus running the static initializer.
3. `SomeLib` then can use the factory to create an instance for `SomeInterface`.

   ```
   SomeInterface si = SomeFactory.createSomeObject();
   ```

Comment: you could also use a prototype, depending on the lifecycle

Answer (score 1):

you can try to instantiate the class with this:

```
Class.forName("com.bla.yourclass").newInstance();
```

Comment: Yes, but in Overdoses case, SomeLib shall not know the names of SomeInterface implementors (loose coupling)

Answer (score 0):

I'd declare the classes, that implement your interface in a flat file (either java properties or xml) on the classpath. Your library can look for the file, read the class names and create instances. I think, that's a typical approach.

Then you do not need reflection to search the classpath for implementors but just invocation to create instances.